# Gulp unbuild from salesforce org

Tags: angularjs, build, salesforce, metadata, gulp

I am actually developping an application in a salesforce environment using MavensMate and Sublime Text 3, built with Gulp, in AngularJS from Yeoman.

I managed to connect my built application to salesforce thanks to CodeScience gulp angular tutorial on youtube, and can now develop my application locally, test it, build it, and finally send it to our org.

Right now i'm asking myself a question:

How can another person unbuild the metadata and static resources that I have built with Gulp after retrieving them using MavensMate ?

Isn't there any way to do it just so that we can work on different stuff on the project at the same time ?

That would be truely awesome, I haven't found a way to do it yet but will keep this post updated if I do.

Thanks for any help you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 1):

I am the Director of Engineering at CodeScience.  I'm glad you've had success with the Yeoman generator for our local SFDC UI stack.  We use it a great deal internally to rapidly build SPAs in Salesforce.  If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to share code from a single or multiple SPAs (single page apps) with another developer.  A better solution than sharing code through the static resource would be to use a version control solution like Git and a repository host like GitHub.  We all work of our own branches (managed by push/pull requests) and branching in general works very well with our local build stack for rapid prototyping.  Let me know if I, our or team can help you any further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer doddsilla, is there a way to build and deploy the project to salesforce without minifying the code using gulp ? Like deactivating the minifying module for a while ?

Comment: I asked one of our devs, and he said if you comment out Uglify around line 106 of our build.js file, the output should not be minified.  Try this approach and let me know if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is not to unbuild the static resource, but to distribute the source code to the other developers so they can build a new minified resource.